# How does red iron oxide (Fe2O3) increase the burn rate of sugar rocket fuel?

Tags: electrochemistry, kinetics

My question is similar to  [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16427/electron-transfer-in-organic-reactions-why-does-brown-iron-oxide-improve-burn-r), however that question seems to ask about how it improves combustion in general, not specifically with respect to sugar rocket fuel.

The answer to this question states:

> Now molecular oxygen is by far a better oxidisation agent than Fe2O3 however in fine powdered form, these iron oxide molecules are in immediate contact with your OM; we do not need to wait for molecular oxygen to be used up and for more to diffuse in.

If I am understanding correctly, this is suggesting that the iron oxide acts as an oxidation agent when molecular oxygen is not available. However, in sugar rocket fuel, there should be potassium nitrate in direct contact with the sucrose molecules (especially because the fuel mix was dissolved in water before heating), so I feel like this point is invalidated.

This is what I think the reactions is for the oxidation using potassium nitrate:
$\ce{48KNO_3 + 5C_12H_22O_11 -> 24K_2CO_3 + 36CO_2 + 55H_2O + 24N2}$

And for iron (iii) oxide:

$\ce{24Fe_2O_3 + C_12H_22O_11 -> 48FeO + 12CO_2 + 11H_2O}$

Is the increase in burn rate due to a lower activation energy or a faster reaction rate for the reaction with the iron oxide than the reaction with the potassium nitrate? Or is it that only 9.6 molecules of potassium nitrate are consumed for every sucrose molecule, while 24 molecules of iron oxide are consumed for every sucrose molecule?

Comment: Maybe is it simply a catalytic effect of $\ce{Fe2O3}$ ? It reminds me of another experiment. If you try to burn sugar cube with a match or with a flame, it does not work. Sugar is melting and transformed into caramel but does not burn : no flame !. But if, before burning, you rub the surface of the cube with ashes, it burns properly when touched by a flame. This is a catalytic effect.

Comment: @Maurice How does the catalytic effect of iron oxide work?

Comment: I don't know how the catalytic effect of ashes or iron oxide on sugar burning works.

Comment: @Maurice do you know how I would be able to find that out?

Comment: I don't know how and where to find out this information. I don't even know if the explanation of the catalytic effect has been published somewhere.

Comment: @Maurice OK. Thank you for your help.